# Selendroid vs Appium: Syntax of x-path using UIAutomatorViewer

Tags: automation, appium, selendroid

There must be a very easy solution to my question, which i am unable to figure out. UIAutomatorViewer gives information of object, which can be used for Appium.
Following is the example for Appium:
`xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'digit5')]")`

See more at: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.ca/2015/10/ui-automator-viewer-get-android-app.html#sthash.ii6U2aHA.dpuf

I am using Selendroid, what will be the equivalent format for it to use xpath?

Answer (score 0):

A straight and simple answer to this is :

> X-Path syntax would remain the same.

Comment: xpath("//android.widget.Button[@text='5']")

This x-path is not working for my application which I am trying to automate on Selendroid.

"//android.widget.Button "  is a class, and I am unable to use it for Selendroid. I am using UIAutomatorViewer to extract this information.

Comment: @SalmanArshad : could you share the block of code that you are trying. Please add it to the question itself.

Comment: Here is an example:
**SELENDROID:** This is working for Selendroid.
`(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Access for all guest users")).click();`
but not working for Appium

**APPIUM:**
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.view.View[@content-desc='Access for all Bell Media Guest users'])")).click();`
is functional

Comment: `By.linkText` is another locator strategy while `By.xpath` is different. It complicates your question.

Comment: **APPIUM:**
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//android.view.View[@content-desc='Access for all Bell Media Guest users'])")).click();`
is functional but dose not work for selendroid

Comment: just check for a device where you want to use selendroid, does the x-path value remains the same or not

Answer (score 0):

X-Path remains the same, however Selendroid vs APPIUM response to object differently. Appium handles the object on pop-up. Where selendroid needs to change the focused on pop up window to find the object/element.